# mySql query higher then last user comment

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
 id  post_id    user_id   to_user_id    date time
---- ---------- --------  ------------  ------
  1    100         1           2        10:00
  2    100         1           2        10:30
  3    100         2           2        11:00
  4    100         5           2        11:30
  5    100         8           2        11:45
  6    105         10          50       09:00
  7    105         2           50       09:30
  8    105         11          50       11:00
  9    105         30          50       11:30
  10   105         32          50       11:45
```

On the following table you can see that user_id 2 has comments for post 100 and 105.
I need to get only the records per post_id that is hight than the first comment he wrote.

so for this example the result will be records 4 and 5 for post 100 and 8, 9, 10 for post 105 because 4, 5 is bigger than 3 (first record for user_id 2)
and 8, 9, 10 is bigger than 7 (user_2 first comment)

clear expected result:

```
id  post_id    user_id   to_user_id    date time
```

---

```
4    100         5           2        11:30
5    100         8           2        11:45
8    105         11          50       11:00
9    105         30          50       11:30
10   105         32          50       11:45
```

Comment: I do not understand the question! What do you mean by user num 2? user_id=2, to_user_id=2, or the 2nd comment for any post? If the last one, then how come you do not need id=2 to be returned and how come id=4 is returned?

Comment: You don't have a post with ID `150`. Do you mean `105`?

Comment: I guess, you can do it easily with GROUP BY post_id and MAX(user_id). Check my answer.

Comment: yes sorry, editing so do you know the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be with a subselect and an aggregation function

```
select * from my_table 
where ( post_id, date_time) >  (select post_id, max( date_time) 
                      from my_table where user_id =2
                      group  y post_id);
```

or if the tuple version donìt work properly try

```
select * from my_table as m 
inner join (select post_id, max( date_time) 
                      from my_table where user_id =2
                      group  y post_id ) t on m.post_id = t.post_id
where m.date_time > t.date_time
```

Comment: no, i need it per post_id and not for all the table

Comment: i dont need the max, because after id 4 and 7 there can be more records and i need to get them as well.

Comment: @GiladAdar   . show a real  clear sample of the expected  .. result  ..

Comment: Higher than the first comment would imply min(), not max().